# Create application specific tables in the existing database of WSO2

Tags: java, wso2, datasource, wso2-as

For this requirement we tried to create the datasource using the org.wso2.carbon.user.core.util.DatabaseUtil class by passing the realm, but we always get an exception saying error in looking up datasource.
We understand that during server startup, org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator -> startDeploy(BundleContext bundleContext) is invoked and it creates a new RealmService instance where the realmconfiguration and datasource objects are successfully initialized.  In the Activator class initialized realmservice instance is set to UserCoreUtil class(UserCoreUtil.setRealmService(realmService)).  RealmService  initialization invokes the DefaultRealmService, where the datasource instance is initialized and that object is added to the properties.

For any of user or tenant related DB operations below call is invoked,  CarbonContext.getThreadLocalCarbonContext().getUserRealm() method is invoked which actually uses the datasource from the properties which was stored by DefaultRealmService during the server start up and it creates the userStoreManager instance and returns the userRealm through which all user related operations are performed.

For accessing the application specific table, we created our own JDBCCustomManager class and tried to perform JDBC operations.  We need the datasource to do DB operations for that when we execute, “DatabaseUtil.getRealmDataSource(objRealmService.getBootstrapRealmConfiguration())”, we always get an exception "Error in looking up data source: jdbc/WSO2CarbonDB".

If we write methods to access our table in the JDBCUserStoreManager its working but which is not the proper way to do.  Can you please suggest is there any other way to get hold of datasources object of WSO2 so that we can use it in the application.

Answer (score 0):

Your description is not much clear. If your are trying to get an datasource object you can do it like this.

```
public static DataSource lookupDataSource(String dataSourceName, final Hashtable<Object, Object> jndiProperties) {
    try {
        if (jndiProperties == null || jndiProperties.isEmpty()) {
            return (DataSource) InitialContext.doLookup(dataSourceName);
        }
        final InitialContext context = new InitialContext(jndiProperties);
        return (DataSource) context.doLookup(dataSourceName);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error in looking up data source: " + e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
```

You can defind the datasource in master-datasource.xml and give it a JNDI name which is used for the lookup.